# When is the binomial expansion with negative exponent valid for polynomials with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

So for a normal binomial expansion with negative exponent, say

$$f(x) = (1 - 2x)^{-1},$$

we know it is valid for

$$-1/2 < x < 1/2.$$

But what is the case for complex numbers?

I was able to see how the expansion would work in the below link:
[Binomial Expansion negative power with complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050085/binomial-expansion-negative-power-with-complex-numbers)

But I was not able to understand for which values it would be valid.

So say for example,

$$f(x) = (1 - (1+3i)x)^{-1}$$

How can I determine for which values of $x$ it will be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion of a :

$$\frac{1}{1-z}$$

where $z$ is a complex variable is finite when the modulus of $z$ is less than 1.

In your example you have to solve the inequality

$$|(1+3i)x|<1$$

to find the domain. Here it is valid for :

$$|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}. $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also tell if I'm right in assuming that for any binomial expansion involving a negative term there must be at least 3 terms that is the constant, linear and quadratic to give a good approximation.

Comment: I'm not sure to get your question. Higher is the order approximation, lower is the error. I don't understand what you mean by "good" approximation. Could you precise it ?

Comment: Certainly. So by good I mean the approximation should be atleast precise upto the first decimal place. Also please you link some resources that might contain a proof for it.